# Is there a GTK builder function to create a *.ui file from my program that I can send to Glade to process

Tags: gtk, glade

I have a c program that creates interactively a new GUI based on user requests.  I would like to save the GTK window produced for later use.  Is there a GTK builder routine that I can pass the gtkWindow handle to and have it write a glade *.ui file?

I have read over the GTK 3.22 documentation extensively and not found anything I can call.  Obviously Glade writes this file format, but I suspect that it has its own data structure it uses and its routines would not work on pure GTK.

Any example hand written GTK code would do for the source to this unknown routine.

A source file containing the XML equivalent file of this code would be an excellent result.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to automatically serialise an existing GTK application into a GtkBuilder file.